# TypeScript + Vue 3 - ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, flickity, vue-flickity

I declare a variable to have type `any` at the beginning of my `<script>` and I later reference it in one of my methods in this same `<script>`. My IDE doesn't complain at all but surprisingly I see a runtime error in my console: `ReferenceError: flik is not defined`.

Maybe this has something to do with the a race condition around variable instantiation within Vue's  lifecycle? It's confusing because I don't have this problem using a similar pattern elsewhere. What's wrong with my code below?

```
<script lang="ts">
import Flickity from "./widgets/Flickity.vue";

declare var flik: any

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Flickity
  },
  methods: {
    addElement() {
      flik = this.$refs.flickity    //ERROR HERE: flik is undefined
      flik.append(this.makeFlickityCell())
    },
    makeCell() {
      const cell = document.createElement('div');
      cell.className = 'carousel-cell'
      cell.textContent = "Hi"
      return cell
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.addElement()
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need for the `declare` here, which actually tells the TypeScript compiler that `flik` is already declared elsewhere (e.g., it's a global).

Just use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as `any`:

```js
(this.$refs.flickity as any).append(this.makeFlickityCell())
```

Comment: Hm, trying this approach "works", but just causes a different runtime error on this line instead: `Cannot read property 'append' of undefined`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. The new error implies that the template ref doesn't exist, and is beyond the scope of this question. Note the error is *not* caused by TypeScript.